# What is network marketing?

Tags: markets

Recently, I have been studying [Robert Kiyosaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kiyosaki). He states that one of the best methods to prepare yourself in business is **Network Marketing**.
What is this, and how can I learn it?

Answer (score 3):

Network Marketing (also called [multi-level marketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_marketing)) isn't necessarily a skill that you learn in a course. It's a type of business model that's used by companies like Avon, Southern Living, Mary Kay, etc. It's also used in many scams (called pyramid schemes, but the aforementioned companies are using the pyramid structure, too). A lot. See here for a high-level explanation (pay attention to the pyramid scheme bit): http://www.entrepreneur.com/encyclopedia/network-marketing

If you want to get into a Network Marketing venture, join a **reputable** company and start doing it. They will provide you with all of the training you need. Your "manager" will make money based on how well you do. If you can in turn recruit other individuals to start selling, then you make money off their sales, and you "manager" makes money off their sales. Hence the pyramid label.

Reputable companies charge very little to join, you set your own schedule, and don't have any hard quotas to live up to. Do your research! If they make you a promise that sounds too good to be true, it is.